# SharePoint page title issue

Tags: publishing-site, navigation

I am using SharePoint 2007 + Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint 2007's publishing portal template. When I add a new web page, current location navigation bar under top global navigation bar displays location from web site name?

For example, my web site name is "inc" and page title is "Press Release", it will be displayed as inc > Press Release.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas to change the current location navigation bar display from site name "inc" to fixed text "Main Page"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just change the Web Site name from "inc" to "Main Page"?  If that isn't right for you, thern you could put a snippet of jQuery in the master page to find and replace the "inc" text.

Update:

Here's a real life example.  On the Home Page of [SophiaThink Consulting's site](http://www.sophiathinkconsulting.com/default.aspx), we're using the Smiling Goat RSS Web Part.  There's no way with that Web Part to specify the Web Part Title; it simply is pulled from the feed title.  We wanted to display "insights" rather than "SophiaThink's Blog", so I simply used this line of jQuery to fix it up:

```
$(".ms-descriptiontext a:contains('SophiaThink's Blog')").html("insights");
```

M.

Comment: "you could put a snippet of jQuery in the master page to find and replace the "inc" text." -- could you show me how in more details please?

Comment: Can we change the web site name after the web site is created in SharePoint?

Comment: You can go to Site Settings and Search For Title & Description there you can change the Title of the Site.

Comment: Cool, for this point "you could put a snippet of jQuery in the master page to find and replace the "inc" text." -- could you show me how in more details please?

Comment: Although jQuery would work, it seems a bit of overkill for something that can be done using the admin screens. I suggest you try that first George.

Comment: I added an example above, but the right answer is to change the site name, as Jaap says.

Comment: "something that can be done using the admin screens" -- I did not find solution from administrator interface, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Cool, Marc, question answered!

Comment: George: Did you go to Site Settings / Look and Feel / Title, description, and icon and change the Title?  That's what we all mean by the "admin screens".